# since they were 10/from the age of 10

Tags: meaning

"**They started getting an income since they were 10**" implies that they began earning money at the age of 10 and have continued to do so up to the present time. It suggests an ongoing action or situation.

"**They started getting an income from the age of 10**" is more specific and emphasizes the starting point of their income generation, which was at the age of 10. It doesn't necessarily imply that they are still earning money now.

Both sentences convey the same basic idea, but the choice between "since they were 10" and "from the age of 10" can depend on the context and the specific emphasis you want to convey.

---

Do you agree with this explanation?

Comment: _Started_ doesn't go with _since_. Either 'They started getting an income **at** the age of ten' or 'They have been getting an income since the age of ten'.

Comment: They started getting an income from the age of 10. What about FROM?

Comment: It doesn't sound quite as wrong as using 'since', but I still maintain that you _start_ doing something at a point in time, not over a period.